# What is AtomicLong in Java used for?

Tags: java, atomic-long

Can some one explain what AtomicLong is used for?  For example, what's the difference in the below statements?

```
private Long transactionId;
private AtomicLong transactionId;
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

There are ***significant*** differences between these two objects, although the net result is the same, they are definitely very different and used under very different circumstances.

You use a basic `Long` object when:

- You need the wrapper class
- You are working with a collection
- You only want to deal with objects and not primitives (which kinda works out)

You use an `AtomicLong` when:

- You have to guarantee that the value can be used in a concurrent environment
- You don't need the wrapper class (as this class will not autobox)

`Long` by itself doesn't allow for thread interopability since two threads could both see and update the same value, but with an `AtomicLong`, there are pretty decent guarantees around the value that multiple threads will see.

Effectively, unless you ever bother working with threads, you won't need to use `AtomicLong`.

Comment: When you write : "Long by itself doesn't allow for thread interopability since two threads could both see and update the same value" , how is it possible to modify a Long object ? I thought that Longs are immutable and I didn't found any method in the Long class to modify the value.

Comment: @PhilippeG.:  Oh, you can always mutate a field if you don't properly synchronize it.  The `Long` class is immutable but its place in memory isn't.