# Populate form using values getting from Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am simply creating a CRUD Application in Spring MVC. I want to edit Student Details. I have created one form which is used to add student. How can I use the same form to populate the student details for editing it ?

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addStudent(@RequestParam("studentName") String name,@RequestParam("studentId") String studId){
    System.out.println("Student Id : "+ studId);
    System.out.println("Student "+name+" added");
    list.add(name);
    return "redirect:get";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/edit/${index}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editStudent(@PathVariable("index") int index, Model model){
    System.out.println("Edit Student with Index " + index);
    model.addAttribute("studentId",index);
    model.addAttribute("studentName",list.get(index));
    return "student";
}
```

Form

```
<c:url value="/students/add" var="addStudentAction"></c:url>
<form action="${addStudentAction}" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="studentId">
    <input type="text" name="studentName"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Student" />
</form>
```

I want to set studentId and studentName in form fields which are set in model in editStudent method.

Comment: Just for your information: for creating and editing it's much better to use POST method instead of GET.

Comment: The key is the usage of modelAttribute. Have a look here for instance http://www.arquitecturajava.com/spring-mvc-modelattribute/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is a very basic question that ideally should be learned from the tutorials and documentation.

Here is a short list of the steps:

- use [Spring tags for rendering form](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib) (`<form:form>`, `<form:input>`, etc)
- create an object that will represent form values and export it from the controller to the view
- take this object as an argument in the controller's method that is handling form submission

Comment: using spring form it is mandatory to speicfy model in the modelAttribute. I don't want to create my custom model class.

Comment: In this case you have to fill `value` attributes manually: `<input type="text" name="studentName" value="<c:out value='${studentName}' />" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need two pages and one controller.
1. for list all students : index.jsp

```
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
    <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h3>Student List</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="${requestScope.students}" var="student">
                <li>
                    <c:out value="${student.id}"></c:out> |
                    <c:out value="${student.name}"></c:out> |
                    <a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/student/<c:out value='${student.id}'/>">edit</a>
                </li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
        </p>
        <p><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/student/new">Create Student</a></p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

2. for show or edit or create student: edit.jsp

   ```
   <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
   <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
   <html>
   <head>
       <title>Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <c:if test="${student.id == null}">
       <h3>Student Create</h3>
   </c:if>
   <c:if test="${student.id != null}">
       <h3>Student Edit</h3>
   </c:if>
   <div>
       <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/student/" method="post">
           <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<c:out value='${student.id}'/>"/>
           <p>Student Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="<c:out value='${student.name}'/>"></p>
           <p><input type="submit" value="submit"/></p>
       </form>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```
3. student controller

   ```
   package cn.kolbe.student;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
   import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
   @Controller
   @RequestMapping("/student")
   public class StudentController {
       @GetMapping("")
       public ModelAndView index() {
           List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
           studentCache.keySet().forEach(id -> {
               students.add(studentCache.get(id));
           });
           return new ModelAndView("student/index", "students", students);
       }
       @GetMapping("/{id}")
       public ModelAndView show(@PathVariable("id")String id) {
           if (id.equals("new")) {
               return new ModelAndView("student/edit");
           } else {
               Student student = studentCache.get(Long.valueOf(id));
               return new ModelAndView("student/edit", "student", student);
           }
       }
       @PostMapping("")
       public String createOrEdit(String name, Long id) {
           Student student;
           if (id == null) {
               id = cacheId++;
               student = new Student(id, name);
               studentCache.put(id, student);
           } else {
               student = studentCache.get(id);
               student.setName(name);
           }
           return "redirect:/student";
       }
       private static ConcurrentHashMap<Long, Student> studentCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
       private static Long cacheId = 1L;
   }
   ```

Comment: I believe that using scriptlets is a bad style and I would rather use `<c:forEach>` instead.

Comment: Another possible issue here related to concurrency: because controller is a bean and by default it has `singleton` scope then it's possible that 2 and more threads will execute methods on the controller. Consider using `ConcurrentHashMap` instead of `HashMap`.

Comment: Another possible problem: using `${student.id}` in the HTML code is prone to XSS attacks. Consider using `<c:out>` which escapes data before printing.

Comment: Hi Slava Semushin ,I agree with you. And edit the code already. Thank you!

Comment: Yet another issue is to replace `Long` by `AtomicLong` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35546956/what-is-atomiclong-in-java-used-for).

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use html `<form>` tag.**

Use Spring tags for rendering form that is `<form:form> ,<form:input>`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Next time, please leave the unnecessarily formatting out of your answer, such as using capital and/or bold letters excessively. Highlight only your single most important sentence or points.